# How do I get one JSON file instead of thousands?

Tags: python, json, twitter

I'm using TweetScraper to scrape tweets with certain keywords. Right now, each tweet gets saved to a separate JSON file in a set folder, so I end up with thousands of JSON files. Is there a way to make each new tweet append to one big JSON file? If not, how do I process/work with thousands of small JSON files in Python?

Here's the part of settings.py that handles saving data:

```
# settings for where to save data on disk
SAVE_TWEET_PATH = './Data/tweet/'
SAVE_USER_PATH = './Data/user/'
```

Comment: you can't append to JSON because it will create incorrect JSON file. You would have to load all files to memory, create one structure with all data and then save it in one file. Save it as `csv` if you can because it is easily append one csv file to another - you would have to only skip header with from second file.

Comment: @furas Thanks for the response. Would you mind giving me an idea of how I can create one structure with all the data after loading it to memory?

Comment: I would load data from files and put them in one list. And then you can save this list as JSON. But maybe `pandas.DataFrame` (table) would be better to work with all data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would read all files., put data in list and save it again as JSON

```
import os
import json

folder = '.'
all_tweets = []

# -- read ---

for filename in sorted(os.listdir(folder)):
    if filename.endswith('.json'):
        fullpath = os.path.join(folder, filename)
        with open(fullpath) as fh:
           tweet = json.load(fh)

           all_tweets.append(tweet)

# --- save ---

with open('all_tweets.json', 'w') as fh:
    json.dump(all_tweets, fh)
```